# Error: Could not find com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha5

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-constraintlayout

I have been trying to add the ConstraintLayout to my project with no success.

In my app level `build.gradle` file, the gradle version is `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-beta3` and in my dependencies, `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha5`.

I get the following error message when I try to sync the project

`Error:Could not find com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha5.`

I am running Android Studio 2.2 Beta 3.

Comment: which version of android studio you are using currently ?

Comment: The fix is to update the android gradle plugin in your build.gradle.

This should work: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha2'

Or you can use the latest: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha3'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the latest gradle -- you should only need to have

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
}
```

In your application gradle file.

If you go in Tools->Android->SDK Manager, in the SDK Tools/Support Repository you should see "ConstraintLayout for Android" and you can verify which version you have.

Also, there was a lot of improvements in Studio -- you should try 2.2 RC. And ConstraintLayout itself is in version alpha 7, there was quite a bit of fixes since alpha 5.

Answer (score 2):

> Use the  latest `Class Path` for that.

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha3'
```

And also make sure that you have installed `support libraries` for `Constraint Layout` in your `Sdk`. Upgrade your `support library` to latest if not.

Comment: I tried using the `alpha3` suffix but Android Studio gave an alert saying that that plugin version is old and fixing the path resolved to `beta3`

Comment: Are you able to build your project or not ?

Comment: The project builds successfully without ConstraintLayout and fails if I try to add it to dependencies.

Comment: Maku sure in your `sdk` it is installed firstly. check that part.